# Returning a previously drawn path

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get the path string from a previously drawn path element using D3. Is there a getter in D3 for getting access to the raw path string or do I have to get it by parsing the "outer html" output that can be accessed by calling D3 select on the node itself. Below is the code for accessing the element as a whole

```
d3.select(`.phillips${SRPCCount}`)
```

the picture shows the inspector and the outer HTML property
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does d3.select("pathIdentifier").attr("d") not acheive this or do I misunderstand?

Comment: I was under the impression that select only returned the complete node. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: you'll notice btw that d3 is brim full of api with such approach -- getters and setters implemented through same function and get resolved by argument count